# How to fire and forget a SQLite database insert on Android?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

The situation is that I have an append-only journal database and periodically rows are inserted into it. This works fast and flawlessly, but I'm curious ...

Since these records are not absolutely necessary, it would be great to implement this as a *fire and forget*. However, I also want to keep it lightweight which is what made me think an `AsyncTask` was overkill (spawning a new thread with various handlers and synchronization).

How would you go about implementing this?

UPDATE: For those that are not familiar with the concept of "fire and forget", it means to execute a task as quickly as possible without blocking and ignore the result.

Comment: Please define fire and forget

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, any disk I/O needs to be done on a background thread, so as not to freeze your UI. So, you have several options:

- Use `AsyncTask`, which maintains a thread pool
- Use your own thread pool
- Use single threads, discarding them when done
- Use `IntentService`, which may be useful if you are batching these records and inserting them in a chunk, as that might take just long enough to make a service worthwhile

Regardless of your threading model, you want to use a singleton `SQLiteDatabase`, typically wrapped by a singleton `SQLiteOpenHelper`, so that inter-thread synchronization is handled for you.

Your best bet for "lightweight" isn't in changing the database I/O itself, but rather batching the records and inserting them in a single transaction. That will be significantly more efficient than inserting them as they arise. However, it increases the odds of data loss, as anything you have not persisted goes *poof* when the process terminates.